# How can I view responses using a webhook?

Tags: postman, webhooks

I am new to webhooks. Was wondering how I can view the response my server creates after a webhook has been submitted. Is there a way to do this through Postman?

Comment: I am a bit confused, you want to see the data sent from the server to your webhook or do you want to send the data to the server from your webhook?

Comment: If you want to see what your server is actually sending you can use a proxy and capture the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following 
[Service](https://webhook.site/) for trying out what the server sends on your webhook. Just visit the website and it will create a webhook link for you. You can then set the same on your server and you will start receiving the data you send from the server on this webhook.

Postman is used for sending data to your server and making API calls.